# Please explain this Objective-C code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation

```
ref1view.hidden = NO;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25f];
[ref1view setAlpha:([ref1view alpha] == 1.0f) ? 0.0f : 1.0f];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Can anyone please give me a breakdown of how this works? Specifically this line:

```
[ref1view setAlpha:([ref1view alpha] == 1.0f) ? 0.0f : 1.0f];
```

It seems that this function will animate the alpha from 0-1 and back from 1-0 and I just don't understand the syntax.
Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`[ref1view setAlpha:([ref1view alpha] == 1) ? 0.0f : 1.0f];`:

Sets the alpha of `ref1view` to be 1 if it's 0, or 0 if it's 1. This is called the **ternary operator**, a shorthand `if-else`.

```
(condition) ? conditionistrue : conditionisfalse;
```

Answer (score 3):

its a ternary operator...would be the same as

```
if(ref1view alpha == 1)
{
[ref1view setAlpha:0.0f];
}
else
{
[ref1view setAlpha:1.0f];
}
```